# Wordpress: get before the latest post with its author

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a code that can get and display posts just before the latest post:

```
<?php global $post; $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=2&offset=1&category=67'); 
foreach($myposts as $post) : ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

but how can I include the author? I try using

```
<?php the_author(); ?>
```

but it doesn't work.

How to get the post and the author?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need

```
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
```

for that to work and to also get `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` and `<?php the_title(); ?>`

You're missing the `setup_postdata( $post )` part

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I finally try a different approach and I make it as follows:


`<?php $cat_id = 67; 
$latest_cat_post = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'offset' => 1, 'category__in' => array($cat_id)));
if( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : while( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : $latest_cat_post->the_post();  ?>`

`<?php the_author(); ?>`

`<?php endwhile; endif; ?>`

works for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?php global $post; $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=2&offset=1&category=67&author=123'); 
foreach($myposts as $post) : ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Another better method is...

```
$args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => 8,
     'author' => 123,
     'cat' => 123,
     'offset' => 1,
);
<?php global $post; $myposts = get_posts($args); 
foreach($myposts as $post) : ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```